# Convex conjugate of a matrix function

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, matrix-equations

Let $S$ be some (not necessarily convex) subset of positive semidefinite matrices.

What is the convex conjugate of the function
$$ f(x) = \sup_M \left\{ x^T M x \;:\; M \in S \right\},$$
that is, what is $f^*(y) = \sup_x \{ x^T y - f(x) \}$?

I'm struggling with this one because there are essentially two maximization problems involved, and I don't really have any idea about how to approach this. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: As a first attempt, I usually try to switch the $\sup, \inf$ and see where that leads. If it bears fruit, then I bring out the formal guns.

Comment: Is $x^*$ the conjugate vector of $x$?

Comment: @JeanMarie: It is just a parameter, no relation to $x$.

Comment: @copper.hat: it seems, this function is not a well defined function; consider $M=nI$, then $f(x) = n\|x\|_{2}^2, n\in \mathbb{N}$ and  $f(x) \rightarrow \infty$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$; isn't it?

Comment: If $S$ is a singleton, then https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205655/convex-conjugate-of-an-invertible-linear-transform gives you an answer. (Use that positive semidefinite matrices have square roots.) Else, the conjugate of the pointwise maximum of two convex functions seems to be non-trivial in general. (See J. Global Optim. 41 (2008), no. 4, 625–632.)